# Why have QString in struct sometimes a bad-ptr?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qt3, qstring

I've got an complicated error. The software send PrintParamters to a Printer a couple of times. At a certain moment all QStrings of the Parameter Struct are broken (bad ptr)

Is there an general issue with QStrings in Structs?

here is the struct I'm using:

```
typedef struct RecorderPrintParam {
  ES_DataType xxxxxxxxxx;
  bool  xxxxxxxxxxx;
  bool  xxxxxxxxxxxx;
  bool  xxxxxxxxxxxx;
  int      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  double   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  double   xxxxxxxxxx;
  bool     xxxxxxxxxxx;
  int   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
  double  xxxxxxxxxxx;
  bool     xxxxxxxxxxx;
  bool  xxxxxxxxxx;
  double  xxxxxxxxx;
  QString  xname;
  QString  yname;
  QString  anotherValue;
  QString  opername;
  QString  region;
  QString  application;
  QString  version;
  AxisUnit axUnit ;
  double  axLenM;
  double  xxxxxxxx;
  double  xxxxxxxx;

  int     xxxxxxxx;
  double  xxxxxxxxx;
  double  xxxxxxxxx;

  bool  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; /

  double  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;  

  double  xxxxxxxxxx;
  bool   xxxxxxxxx;

 }RecorderPrintParam;
```

Here is how the struct is been used:
called from a GUI-Class:

```
void 
MyDlg::UpdateRecorderPrintParameters()
{
       RecorderPrintParam param;
       ....
       ....
       param.xname  = QString("abc def 123");
       _recorder->setParam(&param);
}
```

param.xname already has a bad ascii ptr !! ?
I also tried to use just  = "abc def 123" instead of  = QString("abc def 123"); but it's the same error that occurs

This is how the setParam functions looks like:

```
RecorderInterface::setParam(RecorderPrintParam *up)
{

....
...
if(up->xname.compare(_myParams.xname)!=0 ) _newHeaderPrint=true;
...
...
}

}
```

xname has still an address at that moment"8xname = {d=0x08e2d568 }", but xname.ascii has a 0x00000000 pointer

Comment: you should also post the code showing how you are using this struct.  e.g. is it dynamically allocated?

Comment: ok, I've updatet my post

Comment: any ideas based on these information?

Answer (score 4):

you are creating a structure in the stack :   `RecorderPrintParam param`
and then you pass the address of this structure to another function `_recorder->setParam(&param);`

when `UpdateRecorderPrintParameters` exits `param` goes out of scope  and its content becomes invalid.   Allocate it in the heap  and release it when the GUI is done using its values, 
or pass `param` by value to `setParam`

**UPDATE**  there is an additional issue with this code creating  a string in this manner :

```
QString("abc def 123");
```

creates a temporary object, whose  reference is returned by the overloaded `QString`  `=` operator 
the C++ standards say  (12.1)

> a temporary bound to a reference
>   parameter in a function call persists 
>   until the completion of the full
>   expression containing the call.

so the destructor  for  the `QString("abc def 123")` object is called before the `param` object is is passed  to  `setParam`

try to change  QString("abc def 123")  to  QString  str("abc def 123");
and  `param.xname  = str;`   or     `param.xname = "abc def 123"`

Comment: I've tested to pass the param by value, but it results into the same error :(

Comment: param.xname = "abc def 123" ->i've already teste this, this restults the same error.. i thought the same.....

Comment: The only other explanation I can think of is that some  other part of your code is corrupting the stack.

Comment: for my own knowledge, I don't understand the part following your update :
RecorderPrintParam param;
param.xname  = QString("abc def 123");
_recorder->setParam(&param);

If I understand your comment correctly, this code snippet is buggy ???